# MERGE Statement in BigQuery failing with: "an internal error occurred and request could not be processed"

Tags: google-bigquery

I am executing below `MERGE`` statement in BigQuery and getting error:

> "an internal error occurred and request could not be processed"

What am I doing wrong?

SQL1:

```
MERGE INTO
  testdataset.bq_pars_table TGT
USING
  (
  SELECT
    ID,
    NAME,
    TOTAL,
    AVG_amt,
        CREATED_AT
  FROM
    testdataset.bq_pars_table_copy_merge ) SOURCE
ON
  (TGT.ID = SOURCE.ID )
  WHEN MATCHED  THEN  UPDATE   SET  TGT.avg_amt = SOURCE.avg_amt
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN
INSERT
  (ID,
    NAME,
    TOTAL,
    AVG_amt,
       CREATED_AT)
VALUES
  ( SOURCE.ID, SOURCE.NAME, SOURCE.AVG, SOURCE.CREATED_AT)
```

SQL2:

Below one is able to execute and update the required data .

```
MERGE INTO
  testdataset.bq_pars_table TGT
USING
  (
  SELECT
    ID,
    NAME,
    TOTAL,
    AVG_amt,
        CREATED_AT
  FROM
    testdataset.bq_pars_table_copy_merge ) SOURCE
ON
  (TGT.ID = SOURCE.ID )
  WHEN MATCHED  THEN  UPDATE   SET  TGT.avg_amt = SOURCE.avg_amt
```

Comment: Please post the JOB Id for investigation.

Comment: Job ID: probable-quest-199016:bquijob_79851d32_163489ee1d0

Comment: Is this solved? Could you post the solution if it is, please?

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your query is the unmatched insert column and value lists. There are 5 columns in column name list while 4 in value list. Seems you missed total value in value list.

BQ should given explicit message in this case instead of internal error. We will work on a fix for that.